# NativeScript Angular get target element tapped

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, ontap

I'm trying to detect, which element was tapped when there is a tap on the entire page, like js you have event.target when on click event is attached to document.

```
this._page.on("tap", (args) => {
   console.log("page tapped: ", args.object.target);
})
```

What I get is:

> page tapped:  undefined

Is there a way I can get the element that was tapped and how, any ideas ?

Thanks